# How can I fix objective c app not updating UI?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uikit

I am trying to create a weird sort of timer for my app on Objective C. I expect it to run, and when the user enters a time and clicks the start button, I expect it to hide the keyboard and text field, as well as the start button, and show a text field, then start counting down and periodically update the text field that is shown with the current "seconds", and then when the countdown loop is over, it should say timer complete.

I have lots of tests throughout that check if my functions are running properly, and they all output properly. But my app doesn't hide the keyboard for a few seconds after it should, and it doesn't hide the start button, and it doesn't update the seconds visually until the loop is over. I honestly have no idea what's going on... Can someone please let me know what's wrong?

Thanks!

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    
    self.timerSecondsText.hidden = YES;
   

    
}

    



- (IBAction)startTimer:(id)sender {
    int timerSeconds = [self.timeFieldVisuals.text intValue];
    int timerSecondsFifth = timerSeconds/5;
    NSLog(@"timerSeconds is %i",timerSeconds);
    NSLog(@"timerSecondsFifth is %i",timerSecondsFifth);
    
    [_timeFieldVisuals resignFirstResponder];

    self.timeFieldVisuals.hidden = YES;
    self.timerSecondsText.hidden = NO;
    
    if(_timerSecondsText.hidden == NO && _timeFieldVisuals.hidden == YES){
        NSLog(@"visual updates successful");
        
    }

    
    for (int timeElapsed = 0; timerSeconds > 0; timerSeconds--) {
              //timeElapsed is placeholder to avoid errors

    
    /* 5 divides, the timer delay increases as the
     timerSeconds decreases, but timer should run for
      user input in the end*/

              if(timerSeconds > timerSecondsFifth*4 && timerSeconds <= timerSecondsFifth*6){

                  [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.4f];
                  self.timerSecondsText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", timerSeconds];
              }
              
              else if(timerSeconds > timerSecondsFifth*3 && timerSeconds <= timerSecondsFifth*4){

                  [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.6f];
              }
              
              else if(timerSeconds > timerSecondsFifth*2 && timerSeconds <= timerSecondsFifth*3){
            
                  [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0f];
              }
              
              else if(timerSeconds > timerSecondsFifth && timerSeconds <= timerSecondsFifth*2){
                  [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.2f];
              }
              
              else if(timerSeconds <= timerSecondsFifth){
                  [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.8f];
              }
        self.timerSecondsText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", timerSeconds];
        NSLog(@"timerSeconds is %i",timerSeconds);
}
    
    self.timerSecondsText.text = @"Timer Complete"; 
}


@end
```

Comment: You are freezing the UI thread with `sleepForTimeInterval` call. Isn’t that obvious that UI won’t update when UI thread is frozen?

Comment: @EugeneDudnyk so I figured that out but then I decided to call [self.view setNeedsDisplay] and [self.view layoutIfNeeded], which theoretically should forcibly redraw the display, and I called them before calling a separate method, which I stuck the loop into. So from my knowledge, this should force it to redraw before starting the loop, but it isn't working. So maybe rather than using sleepForTimeInterval should I try to use a regular NSTimer?

Comment: Yes NSTimer is much easier for such tasks. setNeedsDisplay and layoutIfNeeded do not wake up the NSThread from sleep. You could also use a CADisplayLink to force a chosen method selector to repeatedly being called to redraw you string and or button and stop the displayLink when time is over.

Comment: Blocking main thread with sleep functions is wrong, other is opinion based

Comment: depends on the framework. When UIKit is used as is, indeed blocking the mainThread is not helpful. There are frameworks where UIKit updates is not running in the mainThread.

Answer (score 1):

below just an example what you could do instead of `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:...]`. Make use of `CADisplayLink` and `NSTimer` instead of interaction with NSThread methods that put your UI in sleep because usually UIKit is running in the MainThread. So pushing the MainThread to sleep will cause lots of problems as you experienced already.

```
#import "TimingViewController.h"

@interface TimingViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) CADisplayLink *displayLink;
@property (nonatomic) NSTimer *timer;
@end

@implementation TimingViewController {
    UIButton *btn;
    UILabel *label;
    UITextField *timerSecondsText;
    NSDate *starttime;
    BOOL timerFieldIsValid;
    NSTimeInterval futureInterval;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    timerSecondsText = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 80, 40)];
    timerSecondsText.hidden = NO;
    [timerSecondsText addTarget:self action:@selector(validateEntry:) forControlEvents:(UIControlEventValueChanged)];
    [self.view addSubview:timerSecondsText];
    
    timerFieldIsValid = NO;
    label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 80, 40)];
    label.text = @"--:--";
    label.hidden = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:label];
    
    btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    btn.titleLabel.text = @"Start";
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(10,60,80,40);
    btn.hidden = NO;
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(startTimer) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:btn];
}

- (IBAction)startTimer {
    if (timerFieldIsValid) {
        if (!_timer) {
            [timerSecondsText resignFirstResponder];
            timerSecondsText.hidden = YES;
            starttime = [NSDate now];
            _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:futureInterval target:self selector:@selector(timeIsOver) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
            label.hidden = NO;
            btn.hidden = YES;
        }
        if (!_displayLink) {
            self.displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(updatePulse)];
            //_displayLink.preferredFramesPerSecond = 24;
            [_displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        }
    }
}

-(IBAction)validateEntry:(UITextField*)textfield {
    if (textfield.text.length) {
        // textfield validation here..
        NSTimeInterval possibleInterval = [textfield.text integerValue];
        
        if (possibleInterval > 0) {
            futureInterval = possibleInterval;
            timerFieldIsValid = YES;
        } else {
            timerFieldIsValid = NO;
        }
    } else {
        timerFieldIsValid = NO;
    }
}

-(void)timeIsOver {
    [_timer invalidate];
    self.timer = nil;
    
    [_displayLink invalidate];
    self.displayLink = nil;
    
    label.hidden = YES;
    btn.hidden = NO;
    timerSecondsText.hidden = NO;
}

-(void)updatePulse {
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", starttime.timeIntervalSinceNow];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this! But actually I fixed it using NSTimer with what I believe is a simpler way. I essentially created a function loop (not a loop but two functions that keep getting called until conditions are met), one for the timer, one for visual updates, so it updates perfectly now!

Comment: Glad you figured that out.